# atomic and consistency(ACID) insertion in linked list in c

Tags: c, algorithm, linked-list, acid

what i want to get is to do in atomic mode the insertion of three nodes in a linked list.
Simulating the insertion of second node in the linked list, if this doesn't go well
I execute the restore function of linked list meaning to clear linked list from new nodes inserted previous.

I thought in linked list of nodes to add a field named "atom" that say second node is inserted together others nodes.
I'm trying to realize a dbms system and I want use linked list for this, taking advantage pointers for save in column data.
the insertion in linked list must in sense to respect property ACID of dbms system.

I need some help how to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct rowlist{
    int *atomic;
    int *transaction;

    int choice; // 0 int, 1 varchar, 2 bit, choice type of data
    int i;      //type int
    char *v;    //type varchar
    bool b;
    struct rowlist *next;
};

struct columnlist{
    int *k;  //key
    char *n; //name 
    struct rowlist *r; //list of row
    struct columnlist *next;
};


typedef struct rowlist rowlist;
typedef struct columnlist columnlist;
```

Comment: Why don't use a database? i.e. Kyoto Cabinet or SQLite

Comment: I know that database are build over Btree structure - binary search tree optimized for read write file on file system. I have study at university in unimi: linked list, bst, btree, grapth. Adding "atom" and "trsn stand for transaction" fields in linked list thus I can know that a node 2 is inserted not individually but together node 1 and node 3. It's a correct design? If something fails I search trsn 47 and atom 1, and try to delete node 3 and 1. If also restore function fails then program exit with some error and try again.

Comment: Why must it be atomic? Is your program multi-threaded?

Comment: I create a "table" with linkedlist build on row list and column list. Column has many cells. If I insert fields I loop columns and I insert each value in suitable row/cell. I want this operation "sorry in consistency way" because it's like "insert into person(id, fullname) values(10,"Nicola Paganotti");". If "Nicola Paganotti" fails I want delete also "10" delete cells/row.

Comment: No at the moment it isn't multi-threaded It is only purpose for create table and insert rows in consistency way. You can show me a development "begin-end transaction commit roolback" design